# How to search an element in Nokogiri using its pointer id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

In the Nokogiri documentation you can find the following:

```
node.pointer_id # internal pointer number
```

This returns the internal pointer number as an integer. However, it states nowhere how this can be used to look up a node?

I would have expected something like this:

```
p_id = node.pointer_id
element = page.with_pointer_id(p_id)
```

UPDATE...to give you an idea of the use case.

I am caching lots of html pages as Nokogiri object and scan them for specific nodes. Those nodes I save to a hash, together with the number of occurence:

```
{"node1" => 8}
```

Right now its saving the whole node as key, but it would be so much more convenient to have an identifier for it. After clustering those hashes I want to retrieve the nodes again -> thats were the id should come in.

Comment: Good question! :-) What's the use of this value? Exploring Nokogiri API? Huhh... ;)

Comment: Why would you want to? The Nokogiri documentation spells out that we use `search`, `at` and their related XPath and CSS specific methods to locate nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the #traverse method available through the Nokogiri::XML::Document instance.

Here is #traverse wrapped in your #with_pointer_id method as a singleton.

```
class Nokogiri::XML::Document
  def with_pointer_id(p_id)
    traverse {|node| return node if node.pointer_id == p_id}
  end
end
```

Now you can do this:

```
element = page.with_pointer_id(p_id)
```

This will find the node with a pointer_id matching p_id, if it exists.